# How to create a bookmarklet which modifies itself using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, bookmarklet

i can drag this link to firefox toolbar to create a bookmarklet, and its name is "Alert Bla", but the problem is how do i customize the title "Alert Bla" each time i drag. i want to generate the name of the bookmark "dynamically" so that each time i drag this a tag to bookmarks toolbar, the "name" is different ?

"Alert Bla" should be generated by other javascript functions, but on the html page, it should still show "Alert Bla", is this possible ?

maybe in bookmarklet, modify the name of the "latest" created bookmark as a workaround ?

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="javascript:alert('xxx')">Alert Bla</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by placing an invisible anchor tag over the text that is displayed to the user. When the user goes to create a bookmarklet by dragging it, they're instead dragging the invisible anchor.

Here is an example of what the css might look like, where `#myBookmarklet` is the anchor tag's ID and `#linkText` is what is displayed to the user:

```
#myBookmarklet {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 170px;
    height: 20px;    
    font-size: 0px;
}
#linkText {
    margin-top: -20px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: blue;
}
```

And the related markup:

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
    <a href="javascript:alert('xxx')" id="myBookmarklet">Dynamic Text</a> 
    <div id="linkText">Draggable Bookmarklet</div>
</div>
```

All that remains now is to add some javascript event handlers in to detect when the link has been dragged. Unfortunately you can't tell if a user has made a bookmarklet from dragging the link, you can only tell that it has been dragged.

Here is an example [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p74o0k9n/3/)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, what you want is not possible. You are thinking that you are going to gain access to the browser's bookmarks from the JavaScript code contained in a webpage. This is not permitted for security reasons. If your JS code was permitted to change anything being dragged once the dragging began and before the drop it would be a serious security hole. Once the drop occurs it has not been dropped into the content controlled by your HTML so you have no access to it.

Obviously, you could change the name in the HTML document to a new name upon an event. There are various events to choose from depending on how you want your UI to work. The user could then drag the link with the new name into the bookmark area to create a bookmark.

You tagged this with Firefox so I should mention: You could create a Firefox extension that did this. However, it could do so because it runs within a significantly higher security context and has access to all bookmarks, etc.